# Seagate Barracuda 7200.11 Failing Again

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, hard-drive-failure

I've got one of the infamous Barracuda 7200.11 hard drives (ST3500320AS), and it ran fine for several years, then failed with a bunch of LBA read errors.  It was still under warranty, so I got it replaced by Seagate.  About 5 months later, the replacement failed in exactly the same way.  I was concerned, but I thought I might have gotten a lemon as a replacement, and we're talking about a drive with a bad failure record, so I got another replacement.

Now, less than 3 months later, it has happened again.  The drive is still under warranty, but I don't think I'll get another one. I wonder, though if the problem is something else about this machine.

I'm running Ubuntu (and have been for quite some time).  I've got two drives in the machine, and only one ever seems to fail, although the "good" drive is an old PATA drive I had lying around. I've replaced the SATA cable.  I've got other machines, and I've never had another drive fail.

What else should I be looking at?